# Using IN subquery in Entity Framework using Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, subquery

I have the following tables in my database:

```
- Reservation
- TrainStation
- Train
- Traveller
- Reservation_Traveller
- TrainSeats: Attributes are: Train_Id, Seat, Traveller_Id
```

I want to find the TrainSeats rows of a particular Reservation

I have a `Reservation` object that contains an `ICollection<Traveller>` property containing the travellers of which I want to remove their seats from the TrainSeats table. I fetched the reservation object from the database like this:

```
var reservation = db.Reservation.Where(r => r.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

So I want to do something like this:

```
db.TrainSeats.Where(ts => ts.Traveller_Id IN reservation.Travellers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select the travelers id:

```
var ids=reservation.Travellers.Select(e=>e.Id);
```

Then use `Contains` extension method which is translated into `IN` in sql:

```
var query=db.TrainSeats.Where(ts => ids.Contains(ts.Traveller_Id));
```

I guess if you use the FK property and navigation properties you can do it in one query:

```
var query= db.Travellers.Where(e=>e.ReservationId==id).SelectMany(t=>t.TrainSeats);
```

Comment: This is causing a NotSupportedException, the message is: {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Traveller'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}

Comment: Did you select the ids? you need to select an scalar property to use `Contains` as I show in my answer, in your case it would be traveler ids. That error is because you are using Contains comparing with entities instead of scalar value

Comment: I got it working, it was another condition that caused the exception. Thanks.